# How to enable disabled movement keys in netrw?

Tags: key-bindings, cursor-movement, netrw, filesystem

Recently I started using and learning Vim. I turned off movement keys in my `.vimrc` file like this:

```
noremap <Up> <NOP>
noremap <Down> <NOP>
noremap <Left> <NOP>
noremap <Right> <NOP>
noremap h <NOP>
noremap j <NOP>
noremap k <NOP>
noremap l <NOP>
```

However, I'd like to use netrw file browser, but I can't navigate in it without movement keys (<kbd>h</kbd>, <kbd>j</kbd>, <kbd>k</kbd>, and <kbd>l</kbd>, or arrow keys), since I disabled them. Is there a way to allow movement keys *in* netrw (basically, allow movement only when a cursor in it)?

Comment: I would recommend a different approach, keep `h`, `j`, `k`, and `l`. They are small movement keys, but often necessary

Comment: This might be sidestepping the question a little bit, but why have disabled all of those? I can't really see much benefit in removing a fundamental feature.

Comment: I don't understand, what do you use for movement if all your movement keys are locked?

Comment: @EnanAjmain I'm guessing: f, t, F, T, w, b, W, B, e, E, ge, gE, /, +, -, G, H, M, L, |, etc. See also: vim hard-mode. ...although, all those commands also work in netrw, so  ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My *real* answer is "don't do that", but if you insist, you could do something like:

```
noremap <expr> h &filetype ==? 'netrw' ? 'h' : ''
noremap <expr> j &filetype ==? 'netrw' ? 'j' : ''
noremap <expr> k &filetype ==? 'netrw' ? 'k' : ''
noremap <expr> l &filetype ==? 'netrw' ? 'l' : ''
```

These commands create mappings that check the filetype, and then either perform an hjkl movement or do nothing, accordingly.

See `:help :map-expression` for details on how this works.

Answer (score 1):

Since you said you're learning vim, I'd point you to learn your way through `autocmd`. Take a look at [this](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/12.html).

I myself am pretty beginner at vimming, so if the solution doesn't work don't think you couldn't pull it off, it's probably because my solution is wrong. But try this anyway.

Put these lines in your `.vimrc` :

```
augroup FiletypeSpecificMappings
    autocmd FileType netrw noremap <buffer> j j
    autocmd FileType netrw noremap <buffer> k k
    autocmd FileType netrw noremap <buffer> h h
    autocmd FileType netrw noremap <buffer> l l
augroup END
```

Here if `netrw` is opened its local buffer will have the above key mappings, not any other buffers. I searched for ways to compress these four lines into one but couldn't find any.

Comment: Rather use `unmap`

Comment: Yeah, like I said, I don't know much about vim myself. You can put in another answer maybe?

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt You can't do a buffer-local `unmap`, so that wouldn't really work, I think.