# How do I enable mouse in netrw only (terminal vim)?

Tags: vimrc, key-bindings, vimscript, netrw, mouse

I would like to be able to use my mouse to scroll and click on directories to expand them in netrw. I don't want the mouse to be on for any other filetype/buffertype, so that I can still highlight/copy/paste as normal. I tried a couple ways:

1. I created a `~/.vim/plugin/netrw.vim` script:

```
setlocal mouse=n
nnoremap <buffer> <LeftMouse> <LeftMouse> :norm 0 <CR>
```

But this leaves the mouse on even after I switch windows or close the netrw window. I also tried putting the `netrw.vim` script in ~`/.vim/ftdetect/` to see if it makes a difference, but it doesn't.

2. I remapped my mouse buttons in my `.vimrc` file to shift-mouse_button hoping [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4911168/13020139) would allow me to toggle off mouse only while that button is pressed, but it didn't.

```
set mouse=n
nnoremap <LeftMouse> <S-LeftMouse>
nnoremap <RightMouse> <S-RightMouse>
```

3. I also tried including this in my `.vimrc`, on top of what I wrote above in (1):

```
function! TurnOffMouse()
   set mouse=
endfunction`

noremap <LeftMouse> :call TurnOffMouse() <CR><LeftMouse>
noremap <RightMouse> :call TurnOffMouse() <CR><RightMouse>
```

After I use netrw with mouse and switch to a non-netrw window, I have to click the right mouse button twice to get the normal context menu to come up for copy and paste. Is there a way to do it in one click? The left mouse button also doesn't call turn off mouse after the netrw script is loaded.

4. [This answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/15443/33778) uses map-expression and checks filetype, but would doing something like this work (for example only remapping left mouse if filetype == netrw) if mouse isn't set to begin with?

Seems like if mouse isn't set, then it doesn't matter what my custom mouse remappings are, they won't be called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Riffing off of [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/697095/1270397), I added these lines to my `.vimrc` to enable mouse support only when starting, entering, or leaving netrw buffer.

```
function! NetrwMouseOn()
     set mouse=n
endfunction

function! NetrwMouseOff()
     set mouse=
endfunction


au FileType netrw :call NetrwMouseOn()
au FileType netrw au BufEnter <buffer> :call NetrwMouseOn() 
au FileType netrw au BufLeave <buffer> :call NetrwMouseOff()

" Map every left click to enter button
au FileType netrw nmap <buffer> <LeftMouse> <LeftMouse> <CR>
```