# How can I use let `g:netrw_keepdir = 0` for folders and `autochdir` for files?

Tags: vimscript, netrw

Normally I want to use `autochdir` to

> change to the directory containing the file which was opened or selected

However, in netrw, there's a warning

> However, the autochdir option:
>
> ```
> :set acd
> ```
>
> is problematic.  Autochdir sets the current directory to that containing the file you edit; this apparently also applies to directories.  In other words, autochdir sets the current directory to that containing the "file" (even if that "file" is itself a directory).

I want to make the current directory to be the directory contain the file (for files), or the browsing directory (for directories). How can I do that?

---

Currently I use

```
set autochdir
let g:netrw_keepdir = 0
autocmd BufEnter * if isdirectory(expand("%")) | set noautochdir | else | set autochdir | end
```

Is there any possible problem with that approach, or is there a better one?

---

#### Related

[How to set the current working directory in vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2288756/how-to-set-working-current-directory-in-vim) doesn't mention this.

[How do I enable mouse in netrw only (terminal vim)?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/29381/how-do-i-enable-mouse-in-netrw-only-terminal-vim) uses a nested autocommand; maybe the same trick will help here?

There's also a page on the [tips wiki](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Set_working_directory_to_the_current_file#Vim_commands) about the current directory that might help.

Comment: Actually (at the time of writing) I use https://gist.github.com/user202729/483421a9e88af58def12f2e085dc1c02 instead because the original attempt has some issues (I can't remember which)